# Quarkus - 413 Request Entity Too Large

Tags: java, quarkus, resteasy, multipart, http-status-code-413

I am developing a Quarkus application and using RESTEasy Reactive. One of the endpoints receives a multipart/form-data mime type object but when I try to use it sometimes the "413 - Request Entity too Large" error occurs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After digging the [Quarkus documentation](https://quarkus.io/guides/http-reference), the property you really need to configure is this:

```
quarkus.http.limits.max-form-attribute-size
```

I have set this to 4M (4 megabytes), like this, on my application.yaml file, but of course you can configure it for any value you may want:

```
quarkus:
    http:
        limits:
            max-form-attribute-size: 4M
```

Keep in mind that if you are using an application.properties file instead, you should do it like this:

```
quarkus.http.limits.max-form-attribute-size=4M
```

Comment: what is the default value ?

Answer (score 3):

My very same problem does not solve by @hugo solution. I fixed it using property `quarkus.http.limits.max-body-size`

Comment: I would say that property works when you have an endpoint that receives a JSON as the body. For the scenario of this question we are receiving a multipart/form-data so the max-form-attribute-size should be used